# getJSON callback not called when requesting a Facebook user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spotify

I am successfully authenticating a user to Facebook through my Spotify app, but then I try to request the user information and my .getJSON callback is never called. Here's my code :

```
auth.authenticateWithFacebook(facebookAppId, facebookPermissions, {
onSuccess: function(accessToken, ttl) {
    var request_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me';
    var url = request_url + '?access_token=' + accessToken;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      alert("Working");
    });
  },
onFailure: function(error) {
  console.log("Authentication failed with error: " + error);   
},
onComplete: function() { }
});
```

I tried with $.ajax, adding &callback=?, &callback=myFunction but nothing ever worked... Anyone have an idea of the issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add graph.facebook.com to the `RequiredPermissions` key in your `manifest.json` file.